# role based access control does not work spring and auth0

Tags: spring, spring-security, auth0

[Role access does not work while using hasAuthority or hasRole.][1]
Code:

```
private static String REALM = "MY_TEST_REALM";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
            .forRS256(apiAudience, issuer)
            .configure(http)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/es/status").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/all").hasRole(Role.ADMIN.getValue())
            // .antMatchers("/users/all").hasRole("ADMIN") this also donot 
             work
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security",
                    "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

}

Error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-07-23T06:07:25.962+0000",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Forbidden",
"path": "/users/all"
}
```

Error when using @PreAuthorize and @Secured

```
{
"globalError": true,
"errorMessage": "You don't have permission to perform this request, 
 authorization has been denied!",
"status": 403,
"detail": "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException",
"timeStamp": 1532327263857,
"errors": {}
}
```

Stored all Auth0 users in MongoDb. Now i want to get all user details using my ADMIN but the admin access donot work. @PreAuthorize and @Secured also donot work.

Comment: Use code template to display your code instead of an image.

Comment: 1st : Pls avoid adding image. You can add your Code instead.  2nd : can you add what error you are getting ... Do not work means what ??

Comment: Code Added. Please Help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've tried adding custom rules to auth0 but can't seem to get my roles into the scopes claim.